# Express URL parameter feature doesn't decode plus (+) as space

Tags: node.js, express, decodeuricomponent

When using Express' URL parameter functionality, it seems that parameters are automatically decoded.  That is, percent-encoded entities are resolved to their normal form.  `%20` is replaced with a space.

However, a plus `+` is not replaced with a space.  This is presumably because Express is using `decodeURIComponent()` internally, which also does not replace plus `+` with a space.  Simple example code:

```
app.get('/:sourceFile', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.sourceFile);
});
```

If you request `/test%20test`, then you get `test test` on the console.  If you request `/test+test`, then you get `test+test` on the console.

Is there a way to change this mode of operation in Express 4?  Is this a bug?

Comment: The decoding is currently (4.9.5) [defined in `router/layer.js`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.9.5/lib/router/layer.js#L131-L151), using `decodeURIComponent()` as you suspected, and I don't see any options to modify that behavior (`decode_param` is defined and referenced only as a local within the module scope) without a PR.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for digging into that.  I suppose I can create some middleware to replace `+` with `%20`, but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: Have you tried extending decodeURIComponent() and using it in your app.

Comment: @liberalTGM I haven't, but I'd be reluctant to do so.  I would have to override it globally, which could have an effect on other code outside my own.

Comment: You can extend it without changing the prototype. Instantiate a new instance wherever you need to use this function.

Comment: @liberalTGM Its usage is built into Express.  I'd have to modify Express, changing behavior for everything in my application relying on Express.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use + to represent a space in the "URI part" of your request. You can't do that. A plus sign is translated to a space only in query strings.

It is not a bug. In URI specs (page 12/13 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), plus sign is a reserved character, not meant to be translated as a space.